# Who is the FIRST First Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who, actor-identification

In the Doctor Who episode 'Listen', towards the end we see

> the Doctor as a young child

We never see the actor's face, and he's not mentioned in the end credits nor on the [Wikipedia page for the episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listen_(Doctor_Who)), but some young lad is going to be able to say throughout his acting career that he once

> played Doctor Who!

**Who is the actor?**

Comment: good question, he does not appear to be credited anywhere I can find. But just to be clear, that's still the First Doctor. :)

Comment: no, in fact this kid would be the 3rd person to play the 1st doctor...

Comment: An uncredited child actor (in a minor role) will usually be a relative of the Director or crew. Moffat once cast his son as  "young Sherlock".

Comment: @randal'thor - Note my comment above. When young actors are uncredited it's usually because they aren't acting in a professional capacity.

Comment: @randal'thor - It's mere supposition. My question is, what difference would it make to the world if you found out the name of this lucky 12 year old?

Comment: @Richard You mean it's a bad question? I thought people who are interested in following the 'stars' might want to know this boy's name so they can watch his acting career!

Comment: I think it's a good question. I also think we're going to have to hope someone gets to ask the casting director on twitter if we want to get an answer :)

Comment: I would not be entirely surprised to learn that there was no actual child involved at all -- just a soundtrack, a body double (stuntperson), and camera tricks.

Comment: @KutuluMike 4th if you include Peter Cushing. :-)

Comment: I felt my answer was fairly definitive. Is there anything else you'd like me to address before considering changing the acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum I'm reluctant to accept an answer which was ripped off from someone else's now-deleted answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I resent that implication. OP provided very little detail aside from the name. They offered no sourcing and no indication of where they'd got the details. Their entire answer (which I've credited) was "*The uncredited child in the barn was Michael Jones.*". For me to add in the level of detail below would have required me to vandalise their answer into oblivion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> A young version of the character appears in "Listen" (2014), portrayed by an **uncredited child actor.**

I agree with Richard who said it was likely a relative or family friend of the crew. However they found them, I'm sure if they didn't credit them, they would find it impolite for us to put their name.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/191968/20774), the uncredited actor is a boy named **Michael Jones**. This was confirmed in [Doctor Who Magazine #519](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/DWM_519) in a feature about William Hartnell.

> The Tenth Planet in October 1966. Since Hartnell's death in April
>   1975, several actors have given us their First Doctor. Richard
>   Hurndall in The Five Doctors (1983) was the first to step into
>   Hartnell's shoes, metaphorically speaking; then came former companions
>   William Russell and Peter Purves, in various Big Finish audios;
>   voiceover artist John Guilor, albeit briefly, in The Day of the Doctor
>   (2013); and **Michael Jones played him as a child (probably) in Listen
>   (2014).**

The [Doctor Who Daily Blog on AminoApps](https://aminoapps.com/c/the-daily-tardis/page/blog/13th-september-listen/QmvP_Y3fXuvl3QE6Pmw3X6pZGD7R3163x) (usually a reliable source of information about the show) indicates that he was chosen for his resemblance to a young Hartnell.

> Archive footage inserted in post-production indicated that this was
>   the same barn occupied by the War Doctor in The Day of the Doctor.
>   Michael Jones was cast as the young Doctor, after the crew noticed his
>   resemblance to a photo of William Hartnell as a child.

No indication is given as to where they located him from and/or whether he was a relative of the crew or production team (as is common for uncredited child cameos on BBC programmes) or from a talent agency.